# Как поменять первые и последние буквы слов в предложении C#

Tags: c#

Я сделал вот так но мне почему то выдает в консоли **System.String[]** пытался по разному работать со **Split** но не смог разобраться. Можете не придумывая свое решение помочь мне наладить именно мой код?

````
using System;

namespace ahi_mahi
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите предложение: ");
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            string [] words = line.Split();
            for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                string [] x = words[i].Split();
                string z = x[0];
                x[0] = x[x.Length - 1];
                x[x.Length - 1] = z;
                words[i] = x.ToString();
            }
            line = words.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    } 
}```
````

Comment: `line = words.ToString();` => `line = String.Join(" ", words);` ?

Comment: @tym32167 выводит `System.String[] System.String[] System.String[] System.String[] ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разберитесь, как ToString работает. Вы его и к месту и не к месту применяете.

```
void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Введите предложение: ");
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] words = line.Split();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        char[] x = words[i].ToCharArray();
        char z = x[0];
        x[0] = x[x.Length - 1];
        x[x.Length - 1] = z;
        words[i] = new String(x);
    }
    line = string.Join(" ", words);
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Пойду разберусь пожалуй

Comment: `x[x.Length - 1]` есть C# 8 эквивалент `x[^1]`, так, на всякий. А если в таплы поиграть, то `(x[0], x[^1]) = (x[^1], x[0]);` ;)

Comment: @aepot спс, я в курсе, не хотел человеку, который ToString не освоил еще, такое предлагать

Comment: А это чисто коммент ради коммента, для будущих посетителей.